# Lisp macro set-or-nconc not able to get working

Tags: macros, lisp, common-lisp

I were trying to make a macro for binding
variable if it is unbind, else if it is binded than
appending to its value

```
(defmacro set-or-nconc (var &rest args)
         `(,(if (and (boundp var) (not (null ,var)))
                'nconc 'setq)
            ,var ,@args))
```

The intended output wanted is

```
(set-or-nconc i '(a b)) => '(a b)
i                       => '(a b)
(set-or-nconc i '(a b)) => '(a b a b)
i                       => '(a b a b)
```

But my defined macro is not working especially
if i is binded to nil
Do somebody have idea what is the problem with this macro ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The determination as to use `setq` or `nconc` is done at macro-expansion time, not at run-time. This is a bit of a problem. There's also some issues with your backquote expression, as there's either a "," too many (in `(null ,var)`) or one too few (in `(boundp var)`, with the need for another backquote).

Below is at least something approaching a working solution, delaying the choice of using `setq` or `nconc` until run-time:

```
(defmacro set-or-nconc (var &rest args)
  `(if (and (boundp ',var) (not (null ,var)))
       (nconc ,var ,@args)
     (setq ,var ,@args)))
```

Also be aware that using this to gradually build up a list will have more-or-less O(n^2) behaviour, it's usually faster to accumulate by consing, then (if necessary) do a reverse at the end.

Comment: Yes it is working, Thanks you very much! I will try it with consing also soon.